# MySQL Innodb, why does the size of primary index depend upon the order of insertion of records

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index

I have a table with this schema

```
CREATE TABLE `UserIdPhoneNo` (
`userId` int NOT NULL,
`phoneNo` bigint NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`phoneNo`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

I am planning to store 1 Billion rows in this table. Queries are mostly reads and rarely writes. To make the reads faster, I am going to provide enough memory to innodb_buffer_pool so that entire index fits in-memory. I created a data set i.e. 1 Billion records in increasing order like this

```
1,263
1,264
1,265
2,266
2,267
2,268
```

I loaded this data into this table. Index size was 30 GB. Now I shuffled this data using sort command with -R option, inserted this data again (truncated the table before inserting this data) to my surprise the index size was 48 GB. I used this query to find the size of the index

```
select database_name, table_name, index_name, stat_value*@@innodb_page_size from mysql.innodb_index_stats where stat_name='size';
```

Why do we have different size of the index with exact same set of data? Can we do something to fix it?

Comment: This blog provides an excellent explanation with visual aids: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/03/illustrating-primary-key-models-in-innodb-and-their-impact-on-disk-usage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert presorted data into a b-tree index, the leaf pages will tend to be more densely populated, because the index grows only on the trailing end. When you insert randomly ordered data, new rows will be inserted all over the place, potentially causing more page splits, which will end up more sparse as a result.

> Can we do something to fix it?

There's nothing to "fix" so I would just leave it alone. Your idea that fitting the entire table in memory will materially improve performance is likely wrong. However, if you insist on wasting your time, see suggestions in [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110736/mysql-indexes-maintenance), for example.

Comment: I tested this, if I give enough memory the index gets loaded in memory afterwards all the reads queries are served from the memory. Value of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like '%innodb_buffer_pool_reads%'; did not change. I got more than 150,000 SELECTS queries per second. Client was using 50 connections and 50 threads. CPU usage on sever was 2000%. Query was returning within 1ms in 99.999% cases.

Comment: @Aryaveer - What was the value of `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` at the same time?  (`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "Innodb_buffer_pool_read%";`)

Comment: @RickJames I did not save/record this value but I was checking constantly. I remember it was not increasing and there was no disk I/O

Answer (score 1):

The PRIMARY KEY is "clustered" with the data; the size of one is the size of the other.

I would expect the "ordered" table to be about 69% of the size of the "random" table.

(mustacccio provides the rest of the explanation.)